# summing list inside list by position in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list that looks like this and I would like to sum up the values at each position so as produce a list with only three values

```
print x
[[0, 0, -1], [0, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

For example, `x[0][1]` should be summed with the value in `x[1][1]`, `x[2][1]`, `x[3][1]`, `x[4][1]`. Likewise `x[0][2]` should be summed with `x[1][2]`, `x[2][2]`, etc.

the output should look like this

```
print output
[1, 0, -1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
np.sum(x, axis=0)
```

Using native list:

```
[sum(y) for y in zip(*x)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Julien's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320158/826970) answer as it is more readable but to give you an alternative, you can use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) functions.

```
list(map(sum, zip(*x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combine for loops:

```
outlist=[]
for i in range(len(L[0])):
    sum = 0
    for subL in L:
        sum += subL[i]
    outlist.append(sum)

print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, -1]
```